# Is there way to expand all folders in Eclipse project view and search results?

Tags: eclipse, search, treeview, directory, expand

I'm spending a lot of time manually expanding deeply-nested folders in tree views like the Project Explorer and the File Search result tree. Is there a keyboard shortcut or menu command to expand all folders?

Comment: Setting list view instead of tree view in search results might help here.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost and also use `SortBy/ParentName` will make it have the same ordering of tree view!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In "File Seach Result", right click on the top level folder, there is an "expand all" menu entry.

In the project view, I didn't find the feature.

Comment: There's also a small "+" icon at the top right of the window that has the same function. Thanks.

Comment: @meva For some reason I only have the "-" icon and I can't figure out how to add the "+"

Comment: @Hack-R  that is my case as well

Answer (score 66):

In Windows:

Expand all all in project explorer is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad *</kbd> (multiplty), as mentioned before.
Collapse all in project explorer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad -</kbd> (subtract).

Alternatively, you can just jam on the right arrow to expand to the bottom of a selected tree, or jam on the left arrow to collapse back up to the top.

If you want to see all the shortcuts available for the particular context you are in, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Lindsay, you have made our day.  There are a team of us here using Eclipse for some Oracle products, and until we found this we'd spent probably hours having to expand nodes in a wide variety of selection menus.  Thank you ever so much, signed some Madridians.   How on earth did you find the shortcut?

Comment: +1 Though on my Windows 7 with Eclipse Indigo, its working even without Shift and Ctrl+Shift buttons. Expanding with * (multiply) and collapse with - (subtract)

Comment: On Linux with Eclipse Kepler jamming on the right arrow does nothing. Adding `SHIFT` is necessary.

Comment: Careful!  This can crash Eclipse if there is too much in the tree.   It expands *all* nodes, including nested nested dependencies, etc.

Comment: For me "collapse all" was `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Numpad /` but the real lifesaver here is seeing all shortcuts with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`L`

Comment: Tip: when you use multiply to expand all, DON'T select the project root, instead select a subfolder. Reason: if you select the project root, it will try to expand all your projects.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Update for **Eclipse Mars** on Windows 10 (using inside "Search View"): `Numpad *` - expands all in the selected folder, `Numpad +` - expands ONE level below the selected folder, `Numpad -` - collapses previous expanded folder (or if ALL was expanded then next underlying level along WITH the expanded folder down below) in the selected folder. Notice that all works **even  without** `Shift`.

Comment: Perfect answer for me. I will not waste my time anymore by clicking, clicking, clicking...

Answer (score 38):

On Mac: Select a folder and press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW_RIGHT</kbd> to expand all subfolders in the Eclipse file explorer.
Press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW_LEFT</kbd> to collapse all subfolders.

On some Mac keyboards the Option key is also labeled <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Comment: Yeah its too bad Eclipse lists the hot key as Cmd-Shift-NumPad* yet that doesnt work in any context (Search, Outline, Project Explorer) yet alt+ARROW_RIGHT does. Ive needed this shortcut all my life.

Comment: Sorry to be obtuse, by my mac doesn't have an "Alt" key. I figure you might mean "Command", but Command-Right-Arrow causes Eclipse to beach-ball on me. (I'm using Eclipse Luna on Mavericks.)

Comment: The reason is beach ball is likely it tried to expand the tree for your Java resources, which is every jar and every class inside that jar.

Answer (score 23):

Eclipse on Linux:

> SHIFT + RIGHT arrow

Expand all folders below the selected folder. If you do it multiple times, next set of folders expand.

> SHIFT + LEFT arrow

Collapses all folders below the selected folder.

Eclipse on Windows:

> Right arrow -->>
>    Expand
>   Left arrow -->> Collapse

Comment: Thanks! Shift+Right worked. Even the Ctrl+Shift+L list showed an incorrect shortcut. It said Ctrl+Shift+NumPadAsterix would expand all but it didn't.

Answer (score 13):

## Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), Linux (RHEL 6.7)

**Expand Folders**

Tap <kbd>*</kbd> once for each level that all folders under the selected folder should be expanded. For example, tapping * three times will expand all folders out to three levels.

(CTRL SHIFT Numpad * doesn't work for me as it should with this particular build/machine.)

**Collapse All Folders**

Tap <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> once to collapse all folders under the selected folder.

**Expand/Collapse Single Folders**

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

If you want to simply search a file anywhere: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Faster workspace navigation)

Collapse All: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>NUM-KEYPAD-MULTIPLY (*)</kbd> -->Use with caution, if you do it on a large project, ALL the files will be expanded! Just managed to crash my Eclipse!

Comment: It appears that CTRL-SHIFT-R (or CMD-SHIFT-R on Mac OS X) searches filenames only. I'm trying to search within files like grep.

The keyboard shortcut you mentioned is documented as Expand All, not Collapse All, and it doesn't work on Mac OS X. And as I've learned how to customize keyboard shortcuts since asking this question, I tried creating several different shortcuts for Expand All and none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows: ( I'm using [STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts) v2.8 based on Eclipse 3.7, <del>maybe a little different...</del> )

in Project/Package Explorer:

Expand all : <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad *</kbd>

Collpse all: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numberpad_Divide</kbd>, or just click the *small "-" icon* at the top right of current view.

But from wat I can see, Expand All action always make the Eclipse/STS not responding (e.x, we may set class files - compiled or in JARs - visible in current view, which cause too many file to be expanded), so maybe it's better to select specified package first.

Also these shortcuts very helpful to locate files:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>: open resource ( all file types, java, jsp, jspf, properties ...), it's my most frequent use and favorite shortcut;

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: open type       ( for Java files only)

In Search result tab,  there are *Expand All(+ sign with border)* and *Collapse All(- sign with border)* icons at the top right of the tab.

Answer (score 4):

Shift + Right arrow, repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

Following works for Eclipse 4.4 on Linux:

Pressing <kbd>*</kbd> (or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>) repeatedly while a folder is selected expands it's contents.

Pressing <kbd>-</kbd> (or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>) collapses all content.

Answer (score 2):

shift + * Expand ALl

Shift _ - Collapse All

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Focus on Active Task option - shown below.

[image: Eclipse package explorer view]

Answer (score 0):

buttons to expand all
 `Shift` and  `(+)`

buttons to minimize all
 `Shift` and `(-)`