# Eclipse shortcut for 'Expand All' in Synchronize view

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anybody know a way to create a keyboard shortcut for the button 'Expand All' in the Synchronize view? Or is it possible to have the tree autoexpand on startup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just tried this in Eclipse 3.0, but it may work for other versions too:
Simply **press the <kbd>×</kbd> multiply key on your keypad on the right**.

Don't try the <kbd>*</kbd> asterisk key, that doesn't work.
And be careful not to do this on a high level project with many nodes to expand, since it will take forever to expand them all.

Comment: Now, is there any way to contract all?

Answer (score 4):

If you are os OSX, the hotkey is ALT+RIGHT_ARROW. Collapse all is ALT+LEFT_ARROW, accordingly.

The Eclipse preference's key list says CMD-SHIFT-NumPad* but that doesn't work for me.

See [Is there way to expand all folders in Eclipse project view and search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159791/is-there-way-to-expand-all-folders-in-eclipse-project-view-and-search-results)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this exactly as my MacBook Pro does not have a numeric pad.

Answer (score 2):

The default key shortcut for "Expand All" seems to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> (numpad multiply), according to the preferences in `General` -> `Keys`.

Comment: This shortcut only works in text views; it expands folded sections of text. I am looking for a shortcut to expand a tree of files.