# Automatically expand all in Eclipse Search results

Tags: eclipse, search

I usually want to have all the search results (from `ctrl-H`) fully expanded, but only the first leaf node is expanded by default.

What I end up doing is clicking the "Expand All" button in the Search view but this is tedious.

**Is there a way to automatically have results fully expanded?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159791/is-there-way-to-expand-all-folders-in-eclipse-project-view-and-search-results

Comment: Mark `Search/ViewMenu/ShowAsList`, and also `SortBy/ParentName`. The tree mode is very annoying indeed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No but you can use the keyboard shortcuts of your OS. On Linux, use <kbd>Nk*</kbd> (`*` on the numpad) to expand the current node and all children.

Windows user can use <kbd>Shift+Nk*</kbd>

On the Mac, select all nodes with <kbd>Command+A</kbd> and then expand them with <kbd>Command+Right Arrow</kbd>

Comment: Do you know the windows shortcut?

Comment: Any shortcut for Mac OS X? Cmd+Shift+Numpad_* is only working in the Editors and not in the Search Results. All I found is Alt+Right_Arrow, but you have to be on the root node, which is as tedious as using the (+) button.

Comment: Do you know what the term for this function in `Preferences -> Keys` is? I would like to remap it, but can't find it.

Comment: @hheimbuerger: It's not in the preferences since it's the OS widgets default behavior (i.e. Java never notices this).

Comment: @AaronDigulla I see. I was just hoping that as there's a toolbar button to trigger this, one could also bind it to a key.

Comment: Sometimes, there is a toolbar button but most of the time, it's only a "-" button (collapse all).

Comment: On Mac it is Alt+Right Arrow or Alt+Left Arrow

Comment: This only fully opens the current tree if you have clicked on any line in the search window. And you have to click on something because by default nothing is selected in the search window and the keypress will do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac without the numpad, to avoid moving the mouse:

- do the search
- the focus moves in the search view

  (make sure to close the Find/Replace dialog before searching,
  otherwise it would take the focus)
- do this sequence quickly:

  - <kbd>Alt ⎇</kbd> + <kbd>▲ Up Arrow</kbd> (select the root node)
  - <kbd>Alt ⎇</kbd> + <kbd>◀ Left Arrow</kbd> (collapse the root node)
  - <kbd>Alt ⎇</kbd> + <kbd>► Right Arrow</kbd> (expand the root node)

    (For some reason <kbd>⎇</kbd> + <kbd>►</kbd> doesn't expand all of the root children, first you have to collapse it.)

This is faster than clicking on the small `+` icon.

Comment: This works for Spring Tool Suite as well, since it is built on top of Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

On a Windows without a numpad, the following can help to expand the search result fast without click the mouse.

> This method does not expand result instantly, but i found it to be more convenient and faster than using mouse to click the `+` button on Eclipse.

1. After search, `hold` onto <kbd>► Right Arrow</kbd> to expand one search result to its `end root`
2. Once reached the `end root`, press <kbd>▼ Down Arrow</kbd> to move on to `the next search result`, `hold` onto <kbd>► Right Arrow</kbd> to expand one search result to its `end root`
3. Repeat `step 1` and `step 2` until all results are expanded.