# In VS Code file searching, can I expand (or collapse) all results?

Tags: visual-studio-code, search, full-text-search, expand

In the Search pane of the program, after I hit Enter, all files are listed, with some expanded to show results in a file, and others collapsed. I'm wondering firstly what determines the expansion of any given file, and secondly what I can do to expand all of them at once.

This question seems closest to mine, but it's about a different IDE, and the key commands it suggests for Windows had no apparent effect: [Automatically expand all in Eclipse Search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553469/automatically-expand-all-in-eclipse-search-results)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See this setting:

`Search: Collapse Results`  in the Settings UI or

`search.collapseResults: alwaysExpand` in your `settings.json` file

The options are `auto`,`alwaysCollapse`, and `alwaysExpand`. `auto` is the default.

> `auto`: Files with less than 10 results are expanded.  Others are collapsed.

So you want the `alwaysExpand` option.

You can also toggle any file expanded/collapsed with the <kbd>Space</kbd> key or just expand any collapsed file with <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>.

Collapse with <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> and collapse all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>.  Oddly, there is no `expandAll` binding or command.

---

And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67307225/836330 for a command to collapse all the results that you can set to a keybinding:

`workbench.files.action.collapseExplorerFolders` as in

```
{
  "key": "alt+l",    // whatever you want
  "command": "search.action.collapseSearchResults",
  "when": "searchViewletFocus"   // if you want to limit it when focus is already on the search results area
}
```

in your `keybindings.json`.

v1.41 is making expanded search results the default, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#search

> **Expand all search results by default**
>
> Previously, if a full text search returned more than 10 results in a
> single file, it would appear collaped in the results tree. However,
> this sometimes made finding a particular result difficult, so with
> this release all results will appear expanded. You can set
> `search.collapseResults` to `auto` to revert to the old behaviour.

And see [Visual Studio Code - Include context in search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51599104/visual-studio-code-include-context-in-search-results/59230054#59230054) for showing the search results in an editor.

Comment: Yeah, I also figured from the "Find All References" results, when you are in the state where some references are expanded, and some are collapsed, there is no Expand All option from the UI. (There is Collapse all though) :(

Comment: Do you happen to know how to achieve a similar behavior when using "Find File References"? I got here searching for that, but no luck so far! Thanks

edit: I just found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4333 but that is only for the c++ tools extension

Answer (score 25):

There are two quick ways to expand all at any time:

- Click the icon in the top right of the search panel that has a "+" inside a square. This toggles all items expanded/collapsed.

[image]

- Use the command palette (Cmd-Shift-P) to trigger the "Search: Expand All" command. To make it quicker to access, you can add a custom keyboard shortcut: when looking at the "Expand All" search result in the command palette, click the gear icon next to it and it will take you to an editor for adding a shortcut binding.

Both of these *only* work for the Search panel though – despite the similarity, they do *not* work for the "Find All References" results panel.