# Android - Eclipse - how to expand all /src packages at once?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-adt

[image]

Is it possible to expand all the packages at once?

I can't seem to find that option in Eclipse.

It's getting tedious for me to expand all of them every time I start eclipse.

Comment: you should tag your question in eclipse instead of android and eclipse adt...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there way to expand all folders in Eclipse project view and search results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159791/is-there-way-to-expand-all-folders-in-eclipse-project-view-and-search-results)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the package representation from flat to hierarchial.

Go to the package explorer, click the drop down menu, the small triangle in the toolbar.

This will give you:

```
src
- com.landa
           + adapter
           + database
           + datatypes
```